# Installing silverlight 4 for VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

while installing silvelight4.tools.exe i am getting following error:

****Installation Requirements:
Visual Studio 2010 or Visual Web Developer Express 2010 or Visual Phone Developer Express 2010 that matches the language version of Silverlight Tools 4 must be installed before installation of Silverlight Tools can continue.  Silverlight Tools is available in other languages at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=177432.**

I have already installed VS2010 Professional version with following listed component:
[image]

Can any one tell me what else I have to Install for silverLight 4?

Answer (score 0):

issue was solved after replying VS 2010 Service Pack1